# Android Activity container not replaced

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a ActionBarActivity (MainActivity) with a Toolbar, a NavigationDrawer and a FrameLayout as container for my fragments.

When I start my app the first fragment (ArticleOverview) which is shown will be visible (side note: fragment is visible but no data from my async task is loaded even though notifyDataSet is called and the ListView only gets the entries if I touch the screen once - strange, but I don't know if this is related to the problem of this question).

If I change to another fragment with for example the navigation Drawer, the container view stays empty. The strange thing is, if the app will be minimized to multitasking and opened again (so the same fragment loads) it works perfectly and I can see the fragment. So this happens only on the first start and not if its in the ram. The fragments onCreateView is executed and I have no clue why its not visible

The MainActivity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/activity_background_gray" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.danielbretzigheimer.reedly.app.view.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

method in MainActivity.java to display the article overview

```
public void launchArticleOverview(String title, String streamId) {
    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section_articles);
    mTitle = mTitle + " " + title;

    if (this.getToolbar() != null)
        this.getToolbar().setTitle(mTitle);

    ArticleOverviewFragment fragment = new ArticleOverviewFragment();
    fragment.initialize(streamId, "");
    fragment.initializeToolbar(getToolbar());
    mFragment = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, mFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

the navigation drawer listener which starts other fragments

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    if (mNavigationDrawerFragment == null)
        return;

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (position == 0) {
        mFragment = new ArticleOverviewFragment();
        ((ArticleOverviewFragment) mFragment).initialize("", "");
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section_articles);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        mFragment = new CategoriesFragment();
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section_categories);
    } else if (position == 3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (position == 4) {
        mFragment = new HelpFragment();
        mTitle = getString(R.string.help);
    }

    if (this.getToolbar() != null)
        this.getToolbar().setTitle(mTitle);

    if (mFragment != null) {
        mFragment.initializeToolbar(getToolbar());
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, mFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Example of a fragment which will be blank

```
public class ProfileFragment extends ToolbarFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    final TextView firstName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_first_name);
    final TextView lastName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_last_name);
    final TextView gender = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_gender);
    final TextView locale = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_locale);
    final TextView mail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_mail);
    final RoundedImageView image = (RoundedImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_profile_image);

    DataAccess.getInstance().getProfile(new ProfileRequest() {
        @Override
        public void onProfileRequestFinished(Profile profile)
        {
            firstName.setText(profile.getGivenName());
            lastName.setText(profile.getFamilyName());
            mail.setText(profile.getEmail());
            gender.setText(profile.getGender());
            locale.setText(profile.getLocale());

            AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> setProfilePicture = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Log.w("com.danielbretzigheimer.readly.app.NavigationDrawerFragment", "Error loading Profile Image");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };

            setProfilePicture.execute(profile.getPicture());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProfileRequestFailed() {
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

I already tried using androids Fragment and not my implementation of ToolbarFragment but this wont work as well.